# Value doesn't fall within expected range

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have an asp.net web application. It appears suddenly that when I try to open `web.config` file by double clicking, i gets error message dialogue box saying:

> Value doesn't fall withing expected range

and `web.config` file doesn't open:

How to solve this problem and open `web.config` file?

Comment: Open a second copy of Visual Studio, attach its debugger to the first copy, set Break on All Exceptions, and look at the call stack.

Comment: Looking at this [ASP.NET](http://forums.asp.net/t/1836720.aspx) thread on this issue, seems like deleting your .suo file might fix it. That thread also has lots of other suggestions on how to fix it. What version of Visual Studio is this?